# Limit API rate for nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, rate-limiting

I'm looking for a good way to limit my nestjs api rate.
I've looked at different packages but they all limit based on user ip.

Do you know any good package which does it using the user access token ?

if not, could ou tell me if my understanding is right ?

```
IF (DB has record where [dbAccessToken === reqAccessToken])    
    IF (currentDate <= record.timestamp + limitSeconds) 
        => throw "Rate Limit Error"

...
=> Resolve Request 
=> Add record in DB
```

I think my solution could work but I'm affraid it could impact api speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there are two possibilities for rate limiting:

- (Prefered): implement rate limiting on webserver level (i.e. via nginx/apache etc.) (link for rate limiting for nginx https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/)
- Implement it in your application - there is a good middleware available for express which can also be used in NestJS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit)

Its also possible to implement your proposed logic using NestJS Middleware (explained here: https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware) - but I would not advise you to do this as this is quite resource intensive!